# Python not reading data from file?

Tags: python, file, loops, enumerate

My program is suppose to be reading from a file of scores which works all fine and dandy. However, I need to check this file to see if someone has there name in it 3 or more times. My method for checking this is:

```
    with open(fileName,"a+") as f:
    i = 0
    for i, l in enumerate(f, 1):
        pass

    count = 0
    for find in range(i):
        data = f.readline()
        if vName in data:
            count+=1
            if count ==3:
                print("You have already played 3 times!")
                return 0
            else:
                continue
        else:
            continue
```

Enumerate counts the amount of lines in the file. Then I create a loop with the amount of lines and read the data line by line. Then I check if the name is in that data. A small sample of the file I check:

```
Reece 7
Reece 3
Reece 2
John 1
```

So Reece is there 3 times, why doesn't my program see that? I checked that vName is correct and it is, when I print vName I receive "Reece". So again... why doesn't my program find this in the file.

Comment: There's a lot of stuff in your code that doesn't make any sense. Your indentation is illegal. You have an enumeration loop that is just passing, for no apparent reason. You have unnecessary `continue` statements.

Comment: The indentation is a problem with StackOverflow as I pasted the code. It's fine in my program.

Comment: Continue statements cause no issues so I am leaving them

Comment: they don't cause issues but they're unnecessary, it's the default behaviour.

Comment: @Reece The indentation is your problem since you have posted the code here and you are asking people to read it. Whether it is right in your program or not, we can only see the code in your question.

Comment: @Reece people often have problem with their indentation and it causes the program to not function as they'd wish. It's important to establish what we are dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your first loop reads through the entire file, and so by the time you run your second loop the file has already ended. Could do a `f.seek(0)` to start over. Alternatively, the following only goes through the file once:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def check(filename, vName):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        count = 0
        for data in f:
            if vName in data:
                count += 1
                if count == 3:
                    print("You have already played 3 times!")
                    return 0

check("a.txt", "Reece")
```

Comment: This worked for me, thankyou for the useful information. I will accept the answer once the timer finishes